Sum of i.i.d. random variables with coefficients converges almost surely
Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $EX_n=0$.
Then prove that for any bounded sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, one has
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0.
$$
I think the strong law of large number is needed, but I have tried for several hours and get no progress.
My attempt:
For each $k\geq 1$, define
$$
Y_k:=c_kX_k\cdot I_{|c_kX_k|\leq k}
$$
Then we know that
$$
    \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(|c_kX_k|>k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(|X_k|>k/C)\leq \int_0^\infty p(|X_1|>t/C)dt=C\cdot E|X_1|<\infty,
$$
Therefore $p(c_kX_k\neq Y_k\ i.o.)=0$, it suffices to prove that $\frac{T_n}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ where $T_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nY_k$.
Following the proof of Lemma2.4.3 in Durrett's probability book, I think it may work.

@Daan I think it is not difficult to prove $E|X_n|<\infty$ if $EX_n=0$, since $EX^+=EX^-<\infty$. But how can you show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\leq n}\alpha_i X_i\leq \frac{M}{n}\sum_{i\leq n}X_i$? Both $\alpha_i,X_i$ can be negative or positive...

@MikeEarnest No, that answer is full of errors. $\alpha_iX_i \le MX_i$ is false.

Hint: one idea is to split up the sum by grouping the $a_i$ that are close to each other.
Since the $a_i$ are bounded, let $M$ be such that $a_i\in [-M,M]$ for all $i$, then partition this interval into $m$ sub-intervals of length $\frac{2M}{m}$. Denote the $k$th sub-interval by $I_k$, and let $m_k$ denote the midpoint of $I_k$. Then for all $a_i\in I_k$, we have $|a_i-m_k|\le \frac{M}{m}$, which implies that,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i &= 
\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{n}\sum_{a_i\in I_k,\ i\le n}a_iX_i\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\frac{m_k}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{a_i\in I_k,\ i\le n}(a_i-m_k)X_i\right)\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{m_k}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + \frac{M}{m}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|\tag{*}
\end{align}
Letting $n_k$ denote the number of the $x_i$ that land in $I_k$, note that $0\le \frac{n_k}{n}\le 1$. By cases on whether $n_k$ is bounded as $n\to\infty$, see if you can use this to first show that, $$\limsup \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i = 0\tag{$\dagger$}$$
Then, use ($\dagger)$ and the strong law to show that, with probability 1, $\limsup\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i\le 0$, by taking $m\to\infty$ (i.e., refining the partition on $[-M,M]$).
To finish the proof, you can use the triangle inequality, and similar reasoning as in $(*)$, to show that $\liminf \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i\ge 0$, with probability 1.

Thank you for your answer! I think it is correct and clever!

Choose $|a_n|\leq K$. Set $ \hat m_n=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i $ and put $E = \{\lim_{n\to\infty}\hat m_n = 0\}$. Fix $\omega\in E$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ so that $n\geq N$ implies $|\hat m_n(\omega)|\leq \epsilon/K$. Then $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i(\omega)\right| \leq K|\hat m_n(\omega)| \leq \epsilon\,,$$ and we deduce $$E\subset \left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i = 0\right\}\,.$$
